# How to tell if command line arguments contain a stream redirection

Tags: java, parsing, command-line, redirect

I am writing a program that takes one action if the command line contains a stream redirection, such as `>` or `<`, but takes another action otherwise.

My first instinct was to loop through the command line and check if each argument equals the redirection symbol, like this:

```
public boolean hasRedirection(String[] args){
    boolean flag = false;
    int length = args.length;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        System.out.println(args[i]);
        if(args[i].equals(">") || args[i].equals("<"))
            flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

However, it always returns false. The line `System.out.println(args[i]);` shows that any redirection and subsequent filename are not being recognized. For example:

```
project\src>java myProgram.Client localhost 1234 > myFile.txt
localhost
1234
```

whereas it *should* be:

```
project\src>java myProgram.Client localhost 1234 > myFile.txt
localhost
1234
>
myFile.txt
```

Is there a simpler way I can do this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: That redirection is a mechanism provided by the shell, so I'm assuming that those are stripped out from the arguments before they're passed to your `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirection is part of the shell’s syntax, not something passed along to the program. Instead, check whether `System.console()` returns a non-null value.

Comment: By the way, be careful about changing the program’s behavior based on something like this. It’s okay to omit color codes when the output is not a console, but other than that—well, be careful about it. People will kind of assume that a simple redirection is not going to change the behavior of the program.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of the redirection mechanism is that the program doesn't have to care. If you need to do something different, add a command-line argument.

Comment: +1 - This is the right way to handle this.  Other ideas are one command with two different command names, or shell-level command aliases.